# iCloud and OS X Server: Limits for Contacts, Calendars, Reminders?

Tags: icloud, contacts, calendar, osx-server, reminders

iCloud and OS X Server: Limits for Contacts, Calendars, Reminders?

For iCloud, there are some limits detailed here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202158

However there is no mention of such limits when running your own OS X Server.

Does anyone know the limits of OS X Server Calendar (CalDAV) and Contacts (CardDAV), if there are any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data repository for Calendar service is located at /Library/Server. Inside that directory is a folder containing data specific to the Calendar service at /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts.  Within that folder is a Config folder that has the main configuration file for the caldav daemon called caldavd-system.plist.

The limits are based on your configuration and physical capacity.  Outside of that users can have as big a Calendar and Contacts as they want/you want them to have.  Apples limits are arbitrary for use of their service.

**EDIT** There is a difference between limits and compatibilities.

**BONUS** If you want to learn how to set up your own limits [try here](http://mac101.net/content/how-to/mac-os-x-server-setting-up-ical-server/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. The link is rather old but informative. OS X Server 4 on Yosemite doesn't seem to let you set limits in the GUI.

Comment: I didn't see which server version you were using, or that you were using Yosemite, sorry.  If you can not adjust the limits in the GUI, you may be able to do it by editing the plist.